# how can i pass second parameter as optional to the route in LUMEN?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

My routes/web.php file

```
$router->group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'], function () use ($router) {    
    $router->get('post/{string}/comment/{length?}', 'PostController@index');
});
```

My controller file

```
public function index($string, $length = 0){
    // boy
}
```

URLs to execute

```
localhost/project/public/api/v1/post/abcd/comment/1
    OR
localhost/project/public/api/v1/post/abcd/comment
```

I want string and length values in my controller, string is not optional parameter but length is optional if i not provide it it should take 0

Comment: Whats the matter of this code? it looks okay.

Comment: This is not laravel... it looks ok if i asked for laravel but i asked for LUMEN. there is a slight differene to pass optional parameter.

Comment: Why do you use a package such as APIfy: https://github.com/megaads-vn/apify to create your API

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lumen uses a different router so you need to define optional parameters a little differently:

From the [documentation](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#optional-parameters)

```
$app->get('user[/{name}]', function ($name = null) {
    return $name;
});
```

So in your case it would be:

```
$router->get('post/{string}/comment[/{length}]', 'PostController@index');
```

Comment: what would the function header look like for controller method: index()?  Would $name (and possibly $length) be embedded in the Lumen Request object or would $name (and possibly $length) be passed as a second parameter to index()?  This information is absent from the Lumen doc.  <koff>

Comment: They would be available inside the method signature as parameters, ```public function index($string, $length)```.